# How to extract constant in the branch condition?

Tags: assembly, llvm, llvm-ir

I need to extract the constant involved in a branch condition.

For instance, in the branch `if(a > 10)`, 10 is what I want to extract.

I wonder how to do that using LLVM? The corresponding LLVM instruction for
the above branch is

```
%cmp = icmp sgt i32 %2, 10
br i1 %cmp, label %if.then, label %if.else`.
```

It's easy to find the branch IR, but the constant is not in the IR.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The comparison instruction is `icmp sgt i32 %2, 10` - the constant 10 is clearly there.

Given a `br`, you detect the IR `Value` that it branches upon by calling `getCondition`, and then look for a constant. However, note that there won't always be a constant there... If the condition was `if (a > b)` where's the constant?

Comment: was about to write the same

Comment: If there is no constant, just skip it, thanks for your instant answer.